# What is the best way to solve $\lim_{n\to \infty}{(e^{i \theta})^n}$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits

What is the best way to solve the limit:

> $\lim_{n\to \infty}{(e^{i \theta})^n}$

$\theta$ is fixed, but you must have a care for cases $\ \theta > 0 , \ \theta = 0 , \ \theta < 0.$

There is an elegant and clean way to do? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit **does not exist** in general.

Take $\theta=\pi$. We have, using $e^{i\theta}=\cos (\theta)+i\sin (\theta)$,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}(e^{i\theta})^{2n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}(e^{i\pi})^{2n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}(-1)^{2n}=1
$$ whereas
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}(e^{i\theta})^{2n+1}=\lim_{n \to \infty}(e^{i\pi})^{2n+1}=\lim_{n \to \infty}(-1)^{2n+1}=-1.
$$

You have a similar case for $\theta=-\pi$.

Comment: I take "in general" to mean except for $\theta=0$, the only case where the limit does exist (assuming $n$ is an integer).

Comment: Don't forget all $\theta_{k}:=2k\pi$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$...

Comment: Yes, I was careless there.